# Delete files & folders under one folder in batch file

Tags: batch-file

Delete files & folders under one folder in batch file.
Please suggest.

in command prompt

```
CD C:\abc\
del * /S /Q /F
rmdir /S /Q "C:\abc\"
```

all data under folder c:\abc will get deleted, but how could I write in Batch file?

Comment: copy those commands into a file named x.bat. run x.bat.

Comment: [How to write a batch file](http://wikihow.com/Write-a-Batch-File)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a batch file.  All of that can be accomplished from a single RMDIR command.

Also, you can't be in the folder you're attempting to delete, so don't use CD to go into it.

```
C:\>RMDIR /S /Q c:\abc
```